# Should the recovery and muscle-recovery tags be marked as synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags

I guess muscle recovery would be a subset of recovery, or is there not a substantive difference?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, typically when one speaks of recovery in relation to f&n they're talking about muscle recovery. If not, they should create an illness-recovery tag (or other "x-recovery" tag) so there's some context. Using recovery alone is just a useless meta-tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think that they are the same. And if not "the same" they are definitely "same enough."